# Number of combinations for creating subsets including all items

Tags: combinatorics

Say I have n items. How can I find the amount of combinations possible of subset sets covering all items, when order does not matter. This is maybe badly worded, so allow me to give an example:

`n=3`, so we have items A,B, and C.
All possible subset sets covering all items would be

`- [A B C]
- [A BC]
- [AC B]
- [AB C]
- [ABC]`

That makes for 5 possibilities.

Say the function to calculate this is `f(n)` and the total amount of subsets in all sets is `g(n)` (that would mean g(3) as in the example is 10). I managed to figure out `f(n)=f(n-1)+g(n-1)`. However, this is where I am kind of stuck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These are counted by [Bell Numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bell_number). Unfortunately there is no explicit formula for $f(n)$, but there are plenty of recursions. For example:

$$f(n+1)=\sum_{k=0}^n\binom{n}{k}f(k).$$

Comment: I just found out about that using https://oeis.org/, which apparently is a pretty great site for finding out this kind of stuff. It's a shame that there is no explicit, but I guess recursive is alright for the problem I'm trying to solve.